# How to fetch the last record of a table using room data base

Tags: android, android-room

I want to get the value of a column and the value must be the last record of a table, I ve searched in online and I didnt get one using `Room` database can any one help me to get the query for that. 
 this is my table constructor

```
public ItemTable(String itemid, String itemname, String itemdesc, String imageurl, String price, String timestamp) {
        this.itemid = itemid;
        this.itemname = itemname;
        this.itemdesc = itemdesc;
        this.imageurl = imageurl;
        this.price = price;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
```

I want timestamp of last inserted record, how can I get it? what is the query to achieve that

Answer (score 17):

you can use this query.

```
SELECT * FROM ItemTable ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This query worked for me

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE timeStamp = (SELECT MAX(timeStamp) FROM Table)
```